# Cant see database data in dbContext through EF code first

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I create my database using EF code first and I can see this database in SQL server. I insert some data to tables, but when I want to make queries on my tables, dbContext contains my tables but with out data.
The connection is ok, as my database created through same connection.

Comment: This question is asked very often. Are you sure you didn't find answers? *If* you didn't you have to give a lot more details. It's impossible to answer such a general question.

Comment: I have this connectionstring in my web.config file and app.config :
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BirthdayAppContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=BirthdayApp;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>                                                                                              shall I have to check something more except connectionstring for this problem?

Comment: Charity, maybe it is better to edit the question and add additional information in a well formatted form. Also give us some small code where you insert your data. Don't add too much irrelevant parts. Did you also try it with a database with only one or two DbSets? What happened?